# SAS PROC SQL VALIDATE

Tags: sql, sas

I wonder may I ask a question in terms of "PROC SQL VALIDATE" as follows:

Which statement about the following PROC SQL query is "false"?

```
    proc sql;
validate
select name label="Country",
rate label="Literacy Rate"
from world.literacy 
where "Asia" =
(select continent 
from world.continents
where literacy.name=
continents.country)
order by 2;
```

I wonder why the first options below is not "false"?

```
 (a) The query syntax is not valid. 

 (b) The outer query must pass values to the subquery 
    before the subquery can return values to the outer 
    query

(c) PROC SQL will not execute this query when it is
    submitted   

(d) After the query is submitted, the SAS log will 
    indicate whether the query has valid syntax
```

The answer is (d)
I was wondering why the query syntax is not valid?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Option `(a)` is false, as it's a valid syntax. See the answer below.

Comment: Answer (d) does NOT say that the syntax is not valid.  It says that SAS will write a message to the log that indicates WHETHER the syntax is valid.

Comment: Double negatives are the worst question types for testing knowledge, unless the knowledge domain is logic evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you have posted has a `correlated` sub-query (`from world.continents`). This sub-query cannot be evaluated independently, but actually depends on the values passed to them by the outer query (`world.literacy`).

Let me explain each of the 4 options,

```
(a) The query syntax is not valid. - False
```

No, this is totally valid statement, where we have an outer-query and a sub-query.

```
(b) The outer query must pass values to the subquery before the 
    subquery can return values to the outer query - True
```

As mentioned on the top, this is what actually happens.

```
(c) PROC SQL will not execute this query when it is submitted - True
```

As you can see in the [doumentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p059a19y50rpgun1bp4ehq0ld34l.htm), a `validate` statement only checks for the accuracy of a query expression's syntax and semantics without executing the expression.

```
(d) After the query is submitted, the SAS log will 
    indicate whether the query has valid syntax - True
```

The same [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p059a19y50rpgun1bp4ehq0ld34l.htm) also mentions that `validate` statement writes a message in the SAS log that states that the query is valid. If there are errors, then `validate` writes error messages to the SAS log.

Comment: Thank you! Then I guess I had the wrong answer. Thanks!!